# Create TableAdapter with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2015, case, tableadapter

I try to create TableAdapter in dataset designer (Visual Studio 2015 C# WinApp with Oracle Database)

this is my code

```
SELECT concat(concat(G.ACCOUNT_CODE,'-'),G.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE) as account_code 
,SU.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION 
,sum(case when G.VOUCHER_DATE <= :fiscal_year then (case when G.AMOUNT<0 then abs(G.AMOUNT) else -(G.AMOUNT) end) else 0 end) as opening_balance          
,sum(case when G.VOUCHER_DATE > :fiscal_year then (case when G.AMOUNT<0 then abs(G.AMOUNT) else -(G.AMOUNT) end) else 0 end) as current_period 
,sum((case when G.AMOUNT<0 then abs(G.AMOUNT) else -(G.AMOUNT) end)) closing_balance 
FROM GL_POSTING_DETAILS G,SUB_ACCOUNT_MASTERS SU 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT '1' 
               FROM PROJECTS 
               WHERE  G.COMPANY   = PROJECTS.COMPANY
               AND    G.PROJECT   = PROJECTS.PROJECT 
               AND  PROJECTS.STATUS = 'A')   
AND G.STATUS != 'Z' 
AND G.voucher_type != 'CL' 
AND G.ACCOUNT_CODE = SU.ACCOUNT_CODE 
AND G.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE = SU.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE 
AND G.COMPANY = SU.COMPANY 
AND G.company like :company 
AND G.project like :project 
AND G.department_code like :department 
AND G.VOUCHER_DATE BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((concat(concat(G.ACCOUNT_CODE,'-'),G.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE),SU.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION),()) 
ORDER BY concat(concat(G.ACCOUNT_CODE,'-'),G.SUB_ACCOUNT_CODE)
```

this code work fine in Toad but don't work in dataset designer

```
Error in list of function argument: 'then' not recognized

Error in list of function argument: ')' not recognized

Unable to parse query text
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Which provider/driver do you use?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i use > Oracle.ManagedDataAccess / Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver)